# Origin of "Given up the ghost"

Tags: phrase-origin

What is the origin of the phrase "Given up the ghost"?

> e.g.  "After 10 years, my DVD player has finally **given up the ghost**."

Does it have a religious connotation?

Comment: It's hard to see how this expression could have avoided being invented almost immediately after language was invented.  The concept of dead people producing ghosts is found in many cultures, and hence the expression likely goes back thousands of years.

Comment: electronics? When electronic devices get fried, they let off smoke, i.e. they "give up the ghost" see 2nd paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke why not?

Comment: _Giving up the ghost_ means dying. A simple euphemism as an idiom, like _pass, pass away,_ or _kick the bucket_ He meant that his DVD player was broken and unrepairable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ghost* can describe a person’s soul or spirit (if you believe in such things), so if you give it up, possibly to some higher authority, you no longer have it and you die. Its use in that sense is very old, but the expression is probably more used now to describe less dramatic events, as in your example.

Comment: Similarly, many electronic devices are powered by magic smoke. When the magic smoke leaves them, they no longer work.

Answer (score 2):

It has a religious source:

> And Jesus cried with a loud voice, and gave up the ghost. — Mark 15:37 (KJV)
>   ([BibleGateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=mk%2015%3A37&version=KJV))

However, it doesn't have a religious connotation in everyday use.

Comment: Which Bible translation is that? The NIV, NCV and NKJV don't translate it that way.

Comment: It's from KJ21 (21st Century King James Version) and the KJV.

Comment: Yes, King James.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I thought it's a bad translation from German, because German does have this slightly colloquial way of expressing that something breaks.

However, according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_up_the_ghost), the phrase is from the King James version of the Bible, Mk 15,37.

Comment: So presumably it comes from the Greek, since that was the original language of the New Testament.

Answer (score 1):

There were Bible translations before the KJV, and this synonym for death appears in numerous places in Tyndale (1534). For example, Acts 5:5 reads: "When Ananias herde these wordes, he fell doune and gave vp the goost." Cf. Matthew 27:50: "Iesus cryed agayne with a lowde voyce and yelded vp the goost."

Answer (score 0):

It appears in Euripides' *The Medea*, from 431 BCE, hence the origin predates the bible by nearly five centuries, at minimum.

Comment: Can you give a link to support the appearance?

Comment: Not even a link necessarily, but some sort of citation with a quotation would be a great addition here  – otherwise, we don't know what precisely you are referring to (it's clearly not identical to the English phrase "give up the ghost," since *Medea* is a Greek play).

Answer (score 0):

http://biblehub.com/matthew/27-50.htm is a link that says when Jesus cried out in a loud voice he yeild the ghost

Comment: Hi Christopher, welcome to ELU!  Other answers have already cited the Bible, though not this particular passage.  I would also recommend you view the [answer] page in the FAQ for what constitutes a good answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Here is the Greek parallel of  Matthew 27:50 http://biblehub.com/text/matthew/27-50.htm